# redirect domain name to local network internal ip (no requirement for external access)

Tags: networking, routes

i want to do the following:

open a web browser on my local network. type in mydevice.com(or something similar) and have the browser redirect to the actual device (192.168.1.x)

the reason is, it really is NOT for me. it is for a product that hosts a web page and i do not want the users to have to type in the IP address.

also, i am aware of dyndns.org and related sites. i was wondering though if there isnt another (easier) alternative since i have no requirement whatsoever to get IN from OUTSIDE (i.e. no external access). i pretty much just want to tell my router whenever it sees a request for some made up domain name, to instead just redirect to a specific IP address on the local network. the only question then will be, if such a thing is possible, is it easy enough to instruct said users to set up.

is such a thing possible?

ps - somebody may have to change my problem title... i didnt know what this was called, which made it hard to google in the first place. so i turn to SO, but then naturally, have trouble writing a specific title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Hosts file.  See [Wiki Hosts file entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) for the format for your OS.

Comment: hmmm, this sounds like it could be a possible solution. do you know if there is any equivalent at the router level? i only ask bc then it could be set once per NETWORK instead of having to set it at every computer my device would be accessed from.

Comment: If memory serves me correctly Cisco routers can be used as "mini" DNS servers.  Other routers????